# Object quick inheritance and Interface meaning

Tags: object, inheritance, interface, kotlin, delegation

I find in [Kotlin: Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) documentation an example:

```
open class A(x: Int) {
    public open val y: Int = x
}

interface B {...}

val ab: A = object : A(1), B {
    override val y = 15
}
```

So I implemented that example with more meaningful names and I have no clue what is the reason of the interface among the comma separated list of supertypes to the object?

```
interface Toy {
    fun play () {
        println("Play, play....")
    }
}

open class Ball(public open val color: String = "red") {}

val ball: Ball = object : Ball(), Toy {
    override val color : String = "blue"
    override fun play() {
        println("Bounce, bounce...")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(ball.color)
    // no ball.play() here then why the interface in the example ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, the interface `B` (or in your example, `Toy`) will not be directly accessible through this reference if `A` (or `Ball`) doesn't implement it.

Inheriting from that interface is probably just added here so that this example intended to show how constructor parameters are passed to a superclass can also show off inheriting from multiple types very quickly. Or at least that's what I gather from the text accompanying it:

> If a supertype has a constructor, appropriate constructor parameters must be passed to it. Many supertypes may be specified as a comma-separated list after the colon.

---

To get to the issue of not being able to use the created `object` as a `B` (or `Toy`) here: this doesn't make the language feature useless, since the created `object` can still be used through its multiple interfaces through casting. For example, in your example, you can do this:

```
(ball as Toy).play()
```

Or in the original example, you could make the type `Any`, and then cast to the different interfaces as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance of an anonymous class that inherits from class `Ball` and at the same time implements interface `Toy`.

But, both of these types are exclusive, ie. `Ball` is not a `Toy` (in your example), so you cannot call `play()` on a reference to `Ball`.